# Font smoothing. What's the trick here

Tags: html, css, fonts

I swear I have tried this a thousand times and despite that every tutorial I've seen swears by it, it still escapes me. I can't see the difference for the life of me. Am I blind? Does it really work? Am I missing something?

Here's my [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xz8Vf/3/) with a test

According to [ICON DEPOSIT](http://www.icondeposit.com/blog:how-to-properly-smooth-font-using-css3) and others such as CSS-Tricks etc, this is the main css that will render a smooth font

```
html, html a {
     text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;
     -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
     text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.004);
}
```

Here some visual with and without

[image]

I'm testing in all major browsers and if these properties are deprecated, I'd like to know if anyone knows the current way

So...anyone?

Comment: Please have a look @ http://aestheticallyloyal.com/public/optimize-legibility/

Comment: I think that -webkit-font-smoothing is not supported anymore.

Comment: Anyway,  for those interested in better don't quality in their sites,  I'm testing in every major browser.. @Miljan,  interesting, so, if deprecated, is there a different way?

Comment: @LOTUSMS I think not. If you compare FF and Chrome, you will notice much better font rendering in FF. So, they are trying to solve that bug in Chrome and then Chrome will render fonts with antialiasing by default.

Comment: P.S. I think that Mr Lister didn't mean that YOUR question is stupid, but HIS question about which browser you are using :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is not an answer to your question, but then again... However, fonts CAN be antialiased in Chrome, but only (for now) if you use .SVG fonts. Check out [this article](http://www.adtrak.co.uk/blog/font-face-chrome-rendering/) with examples. You can see a difference.

1. [Without SVG fonts](http://www.adtrak.co.uk/demo/font-face-no-fix/)
2. [With SVG fonts](http://www.adtrak.co.uk/demo/font-face-chrome-fix/)

Comment: Well, at least I see the difference here, but this is not a case of styles, this an font-face kit. I've always complained about FF not having Arial Black (I learned that the hard way) I had to get a font face kit for it when every other browser didn't need it. I like this solution, but it's still not quite what I'm looking for. I'm interested in smoothing out the fonts in general throughout the site. (If there is such a thing, of course)

Comment: I know what you want, same here. But I'm afraid that there is no a general solution via css styles due to Chrome bug. At least this works.

Comment: yeah, that's why I voted it up. It's a remedy, but my gut tells me somebody knows something. I'll comeback and give you the answer if I don't get what I want. I made it a favorite so I can track it. Maybe I'll put a bounty on it to see if someone comes out of the woods with an answer lol..thank you tho

Comment: Don't accept this answer, maybe there is some better solution. I also want to see the solution that works in general. Put a bounty for sure.

Comment: yeah, hopefully it gets upvoted more and it gets more visibility. I go through this question a lot with clients and I always starts stuttering and sweating lol. We'll see

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, yes there is a difference, and no you are not blind.  There's quite a huge difference between the values `antialiased` and `none`, but since the Webkit folks are smart, they have it turned on by default.  So even though you're adding a rule that is very useful in and of itself, you just don't see a difference because the browser is already adding the rule.

Here's a tweaked version of your fiddle showing the difference between `antialiased` and `none`:
http://jsfiddle.net/xz8Vf/8/

In the end, it's a good practice to add font-smoothing because there are some cases where there will actually be a very noticeable difference, despite default browser styles.  So the styles just help level the playing field a bit, sort of like you do with other styles in a reset stylesheet.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have to be honest, I gotta be blind because I ran your fiddle in all 5 browsers and I don't see the difference. But your answer does make sense, so, I will accept it later if no other.

Comment: @LOTUSMS, same here. don't see any difference.

Comment: Here's a [Screenshot](http://bit.ly/1g47VGN) of what my fiddle looks like to me (Chrome, MacOS).

Comment: hmmm, perhaps because you are running it in a Mac. Not quite sure how I feel about that.

Comment: Indeed, the property isn't supported anymore on Windows, only on Mac device.